# Mod_rewrite: Redirect to URL in query string - discard %3f from end of redirected URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess rewrite rule which takes incoming requests of the form:

```
IN 1) http://some.domain.com/path/to/index.htm?url=http://take.me/
IN 2) http://some.domain.com/path/to/index.htm?url=http://take.me/another/path/file.htm?key1=val1&key2+val2
```

What I want to do is have the rule extract the value of the `url` key and redirect to its value, ergo:

```
OUT 1) http://take.me/
OUT 2) http://take.me/another/path/file.htm?key1=val1&key2=val2
```

The following condition and rule works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ %1? [R,L]`
```

However in the case of OUT 2 I'm finding that the resultant URL seen in the browser address bar is:

```
http://take.me/another/path/file.htm?key1=val1&key2+val2%3f
```

So the problem is that a `%3f` (percent encoded question mark) is appended to the resultant URL. The problem is caused by the use of the `?` in the RewriteRule, but I need that so that the original query string is discarded. I do not know if the `%3f` will cause problems, so to be on the safe side I would like to eliminate it. We're using Apache 2.2.22 so no Query String Discard `[QSD]` option unfortunately.

Is there a way to eliminate the `%3f` while maintaining the function of the rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule with `NE` flag which means `no escaping` resulting URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.htm\?url=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule index\.htm$ %1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks again, but the result of your rule is almost the same as mine; for OUT 2, an unescaped `?` appears at the end in the browser address bar. Changing web browser doesn't seem to help. Interestingly, when I monitor the requests with Fiddler web debugger there's no sign of the `?` (or `%3f`) at the end of the request.

Comment: That shouldn't happen with this rule as you noticed in web debugger. Somehow I think browser is showing cached results.